# Scapy import fails without Wifi connection

Tags: python, macos, scapy

I have just installed Scapy (v 2.3.3) on Mac OS Sierra. 
It works fine as long as I am connected to WiFi but gives an import error when I run my code without the connection.

Below is the error statement:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/all.py", line 25, in <module>
    from scapy.route import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 163, in <module>
    conf.route=Route()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 22, in __init__
    self.resync()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/route.py", line 31, in resync
    self.routes = read_routes()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/unix.py", line 102, in read_routes
    ifaddr = scapy.arch.get_if_addr(netif)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/__init__.py", line 48, in get_if_addr
    return socket.inet_ntoa(get_if_raw_addr(iff))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/arch/pcapdnet.py", line 519, in get_if_raw_addr
    return i.get(ifname)["addr"].data
KeyError: 'addr'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to the current development version from the [repository](https://github.com/secdev/scapy). If you still have this issue, you should [report it as a bug](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/new).